# Создание формы регистрации

Tags: javascript, html

Как создать форму регистрации с помощью скриптов, где ограничения на поля в виде пароля(цифры) и, например, логина (только латынь).

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function validate(form) {
        var reason = "";

        if (form.username.value == "" || /[^a-zA-z]/.test(form.username.value))
            reason += "Ошибка имени ";
        if (form.password.value == "" || /[^0-9]/.test(form.password.value))
            reason += "Ошибка пароля ";

        if (reason == "")
            return true;  
        else {
            alert(reason);  
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" onSubmit="return validate(this)">
        <input name="username" type="text" />
        <input name="password" type="password" />
        <input name="submit" value="Send" type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```